# innerText vs textContent - getting some errors on Firefox

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox

I'd getting some errors on my scripts here, in the first one I've declared a var text(); type to create a box with some text content.

```
var x=$('#x').text();
```

In my second .js I'm doing some handling on this var that ensure my text i'll have less char than max-length, here is:

```
var limitMaxLength = function(element) {
   var maxLength = $(element).data("max-length");
      if (maxLength) {
         $(element).on("keypress", function(event){
            if (event.target.innerText.length > maxLength || event.keyCode === 13) {
               event.preventDefault();
            }
      });
   }
};
```

So I having some issues on Firefox getting this error:
[TypeError: event.target.innerText is undefined]

In IE, Opera, Chrome and Safari my code works fine, i'm getting error only on Firefox.
*Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 5):

`innerText` was a Microsoft Creation, left over from the days of old. Firefox decided not to support it in favour of the w3 compliant, `textContent`. However, IE8 & below do not support `textContent`, therefore, if you wish to support Legacy browsers, you're in a bit of a bind.

```
var text = elem.textContent || elem.innerText;
```

or

```
elem.innerHTML // eww, but it works, eh?
```

or, just ditch IE8 (easier said than done, especially at work)

Answer (score 2):

`innerText` is not supported in FF.

You can fix the issue by using dynamic property names. At first, check which property is supported:

```
var textContent = ('textContent' in document) ? 'textContent' : 'innerText';
```

Define `textContent` as a global variable (or within the outmost scope), then you can use it like this:

```
var someText = elem[textContent];
```

This snippet gives you `textContent` if it's available, `innerText` otherwise. Notice also, that there's a [small difference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent#Differences_from_innerText) between these two properties.

[A live demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/71ncadeq/).

Though when you're using jQuery, why not just:

```
$(event.target).text()
```