# <element>.innerText in component method code does not work properly in enzyme testing. Testing react component with Jest+Enzyme(mount())

Tags: reactjs, testing, mount, enzyme, innertext

Using React+Enzyme+Jest

Hello, I used .innerText property to get value of certain element, see line #5 of my code:

```
_modifyProfileField (event) {
    const { currentAgentProfile, agentsDatabase } = this.state;
    const eventTarget = event.target;
    const agentToMod = currentAgentProfile;
    const valueToSave = event.target.innerHTML !=='<br>'
        ? eventTarget.innerText
        : '';

    if (agentToMod[eventTarget.id] !== valueToSave) {
        const style = eventTarget.id === 'name'
            ? Styles.nameSaving
            : Styles.saving;

        eventTarget.classList.add(style);
        const hideSaver = setTimeout(() => {
            eventTarget.classList.remove(style);
            clearTimeout(hideSaver);
        }, 300);

        agentToMod[eventTarget.id] = valueToSave;

        const newData = agentsDatabase.map((agent) => {
            return agent.id === agentToMod.id
                ? agentToMod
                : agent;
        });

        this.setState({
            agentsDatabase:      newData,
            currentAgentProfile: agentToMod
        });

        document.activeElement.blur();
        window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    }
}
```

When I try to run this method for testing in enzyme, event.target.innerHTML returns `undefined`. Changing innerText to innerHTML is unacceptable due to project requirements. Is it possible to make enzyme understand innerText from my code?

Here is my enzyme code:

```
expect(result
    .state()
    .currentAgentProfile.Country)
    .toBe(country);

for (const location of locations) {
    result.find('#Country').node.innerHTML = location.city;

    expect(result.find('#Country').text()).toBe(location.city);

    result.find('#Country').simulate('keydown', { key: 'Enter', keyCode: 13, which: 13 });

    result.find('#Country').simulate('blur');

    expect(result
        .state()
        .currentAgentProfile.Country)
        .toBe(location.city);
}
```

The blur() simulation triggers my method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this answer :

[innerText vs textContent - getting some errors on Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25429521/innertext-vs-textcontent-getting-some-errors-on-firefox)

in short : 
`var text = elem.textContent || elem.innerText;`

so you could do something like this :

```
const valueToSave = event.target.innerHTML !=='<br>'
        ? eventTarget.innerText || eventTarget.textContent
        : '';
```